# PowerShell script lacks consistency when run through Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have created myself a PowerShell program to act as my alarm clock in the morning. I have Task Scheduler executing it on a time trigger. The problem I am having is a lack of consistency.

Sometimes it will run properly without any interference, other times it will open PowerShell, error out and close immediately without executing (no error code).

When I execute it myself with a double click, it seems to work just fine.

Execution Policy = All-Signed

**Task Scheduler**

**Trigger Tab:**

> ```
> Trigger: Daily
> Details: At 8:00 AM every Day
> Status: Enabled
> ```

**Action Tab:**

> ```
> Action: Start a Program
> Program/Script: PowerShell.exe 
> Add arguments: -NoExit D:\Programs\AlarmClock\AlarmClockScript.ps1
> ```

---

**Script:**

```
#define loop start state

$Snoozevar = 'Yes' 

#Import form module (for menu)

[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.forms") | Out-Null

#Menu

    $snoozeTxtBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $snoozeTxtBox.Text = 'Snooze'
    $snoozeTxtBox.Location = '50,15'
    $snoozeTxtBox.Size = '60,23'
    $snoozeTxtBox.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Yes  # 'Snooze' = Yes

    $quitTxtBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $quitTxtBox.Text = 'I`m Up'
    $quitTxtBox.Location = '125,15'
    $quitTxtBox.Size = '50,23'
    $quitTxtBox.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::No     # 'I`m Up' = No

    $basicForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $basicForm.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    $basicForm.Size = '250,100'
    $basicForm.Controls.Add($snoozeTxtBox)
    $basicForm.Controls.Add($quitTxtBox)
    $basicForm.TopMost = $true

while ($Snoozevar -eq 'Yes'){

    Start-Process "D:\Programs\Winamp\winamp.exe" /PLAY                    # Start Winamp /autoplay

    Start-Process D:\Programs\nircmd\nircmd.exe -ArgumentList " setsysvolume 65535" #Max Volume

    $Snoozevar = $basicForm.ShowDialog()                                   # Call Menu, assign output to $Snoozevar

    $pro = Get-Process -Name "winamp"                                      # Kill winamp post menu selection
    Stop-Process -Id $pro.Id
    $pro = ""
    
    if ($Snoozevar -eq 'No'){                                              # Clean up powershell
        $pro = Get-Process -Name powershell
        Stop-Process $pro
    } #end if

    $rngvar = Get-Random -Minimum 540 -Maximum 720                         # Time to Snooze (9-12 minutes)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $rngvar

} #end while
# SIG # Begin signature block
...
# SIG # End signature block
```

Comment: Is "Run whether user is logged on or not checked" ? If not, task won't run if you are not logged in. If yes, task won't run interactlively.  Is it running on a PC or laptop ? Default condition is to only run if the computer is on AC power.

Comment: Try to add `Start-Transcript -Path "Some\Path\AlarmLog_$(get-date -f 'yyyyMMdd').txt"` / `Stop-Transcript ` at the top and bottom of your script to record what is happening... You might be able to see what's failing or gain more insights from there.

Comment: In `Task Scheduler`, what does the `Last Run Result` column show for that task after a failure?  If you right-click the task and select `Run` does it always succeed?

Comment: @SagePourpre Thank you for showing me Start/Stop Transcript. I discovered my winamp is crashing thanks to it failing  ```$pro = Get-Process -Name "winamp"```. All manual runs have failed tonight, leaving me with ```Last Run Result: 0xFFFFFFFF```.  
I have modified the task settings to give it the best chance to run and I'm taking a look at winamp now.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a summary of the things that can be done to diagnose an inconsistend scheduled task execution.

- Since your task is interactive (have a form), **Run whether user is logged on or not** should be left unchecked. While you'd normally want it checked most of the time, tasks that interact with the user (popup / forms / etc...) won't work properly if thus option is checked.
- Add `Start-Transcript -Path "Some\Path\AlarmLog_$(get-date -f 'yyyyMMdd').txt` at the beginning of your file and `Stop-Transcript` at the end to gain more insight on when it fail
- Make sure to check the **Conditions** tab as there are additional constraint that could affect task execution (eg: By default, task will not execute if on battery power)
- If the task is running under a different user or in a different context (eg: with Highest priviledges), try to execute your script in that context to see if it fail (for instance, start Vscode / ISE using that context and run the task)

If you have multiple set of operations, you can wrap them in `Try / Catch` block so if one set fail, you can perform additional logging and also decide whether or not the task should be cancelled altogether or continue through. (Note: When using `try/catch`, you'll want to set `-ErrorAction Stop` on the functions that have that parameter to make sure they get caught properly in the `catch` block.

**References**

[Msdocs - Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7)

[Msdocs - Task scheduler -Security context for running task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/security-contexts-for-running-tasks)